# Uploadify & CakePHP - some uploads don't send any data to server

Tags: jquery, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, uploadify

I'm using Uploadify to handle uploads in my CakePHP app.  Some uploads work fine

Here's my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.submit input').attr('disabled','disabled');
    $('#uploadify').uploadify({
    'uploader'  : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : '/videos/ajaxUpload',
    'cancelImg' : '/uploadify/cancel.png',
    'folder'    : '/files/video',
    'auto'      : true,
    'multi'     : true,
    'sizLimit'  : 31457280,
    'onComplete': function(event,id,fileObj,response,data){
        console.log(fileObj);
        var responseObj = $.parseJSON(response);
        console.log(responseObj);
        $('#upload-complete').html(responseObj.message);
        $('#VideoName').val(responseObj.name);
        $('.submit input').attr('disabled',false);
    },
    'buttonText': 'CHOOSE FILE',
    'fileExt'   : '*.mp4;*.mpg;*.mpeg;*.mov;*.avi;*.mpv2;*.qt;*.flv;'
    });
});
</script>
```

And here's the controller code that deals with the file uploads:

```
public function ajaxUpload(){
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $name = $type = $size = $status = false;
    $message = 'There was a problem uploading the file';
    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
        if ($_FILES['Filedata']['error'] == 0){

            $allowedTypes = array(
                'mp4',
                'mpg',
                'mpeg',
                'mov',
                'avi',
                'mpv2',
                'qt',
                'flv'
            );
            $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
            if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$allowedTypes)){
                $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
                $targetPath = WWW_ROOT . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
                $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
                move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
                $name = array_pop(explode('/',$targetFile));
                $type = $_FILES['Filedata']['type'];
                $size = $_FILES['Filedata']['size'];
                $status = 1;
                $message = 'File successfully uploaded';
            }else{
                $status = 0;
                $message = 'Invalid file type.';
            }
       }else{
           $status = 0;
           switch($_FILES['Filedata']['error']){
               case 1:
               $message = 'File exceeded max filesize';
               break;
               case 2:
               $message = 'File exceeded max filesize';
               break;
               case 3:
               $message = 'File only partially uploaded';
               break;
               case 4:
               $message = 'No file was uploaded';
               break;
               case 7:
               $message = 'There was a problem saving the file';
               break;
               default:
               $message = 'There was a problem uploading the file';
               break;
           }
       }
    }else{
        $status = 0;
        $message = 'No file data received.';
    }
    echo json_encode(
        array(
            'status'=>$status,
            'name'=>$name,
            'type'=>$type,
            'size'=>$size,
            'message'=>$message
        )
    );
```

}

This all works like a charm for files smaller than around 8MB, but for files over that size, the controller says "No file data received.", indicating that $_FILES is empty.  This is odd - I would have expected one of the other errors if the file exceeded some directive in php.ini.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `post_max_size` ini directive, by default set to 8MB. If an uploaded file exceeds this value, it doesn't throw an error, it just results in all superglobals (e.g. `$_FILES` and `$_POST`) being empty.

It also prints a warning to the log file. But nothing to standard output.

You can't directly detect if `post_max_size` was exceeded. You can only guess based on what you were expecting in the superglobals vs what you got.

On the other hand, you can programatically detect if `upload_max_filesize` was exceeded by checking `$_FILES['userfile']['error']` for errors.

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for your answer, but surely in that case $_FILES would not be empty, and so the server would not return "No file data received", but rather it would return "File exceeded max filesize"?

Comment: Are you using php version less than 4.2? Before 4.2, when post_max_size was exceeded, $_FILES would be completely empty, and not contain any error messages.

Comment: And since you said "about 8mb" is where the problem occurs, the symptoms totally match up with post_max_size. I'm still convinced that's what the issue is.

Comment: Also, please check your log file for the warning. That shows up regardless of your php version.

Comment: Thanks - adding a custom php.ini with post_max_size 50M worked for me.  I'm using PHP 5.3, though - any thoughts on why $_FILES does not contain an error (or anything else)?

Comment: I just re-read the docs, and realized I was confusing upload_max_filesize with post_max_size. When upload_max_filesize is exceeded, the $_FILES array contains an error. When post_max_size is exceeded, all superglobals (including $_FILES and $_POST) are completely empty. This has always been the case for all versions of php. I'll update my answer to reflect this.l